# "error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector", but why?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I am writing a Tic-Tac-Toe program and am writing a function for the player's turn. I am passing in the Tic-Tac-Toe board (a 3x3 array) in the form of the pointer, `b`. The only problem is that on the last line I get the error in the title.

Subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector: `b[PlayerCoordsX][PlayerCoordsY] = "x";`

Just for testing I've tried multiple different `=` values. Both characters and numerical values do not fix the issue.

Here is the abbreviated code with (what I hope) are the relevant bits:

```
void PlayerTurn(int *b);

...

int main(void)
{
    int Board[2][2];
    int (*b)[2][2];
    b = &Board;

    ...

    void PlayerTurn(int *b);

    ...

return 0;
}

void PlayerTurn(int *b)
{
    int PlayerCoordsX, PlayerCoordsY;

    while ((PlayerCoordsX != 1 || PlayerCoordsX != 2 || PlayerCoordsX != 3) && (PlayerCoordsY != 1 || PlayerCoordsY != 2 || PlayerCoordsY != 3))
    {
        printf("Enter the X coordinate you would like to use:");
        scanf("%i", &PlayerCoordsX);
        PlayerCoordsX = PlayerCoordsX - 1;

        printf("Enter the Y coordinate you would like to use:");
        scanf("%i", &PlayerCoordsY);
        PlayerCoordsX = PlayerCoordsY - 1;
    }

    b[PlayerCoordsX][PlayerCoordsY] = "x";
}
```

Comment: Declare like this      void PlayerTurn(int **b)  b should be double pointer

Comment: Why are you declaring a 3x3 array as `Board[2][2]`? That's only 2x2.

Comment: you can't call in your main your function like you are doing

Comment: @Chinna Thank you, this solved the issue.

Barmar I believe it is a 3x3 because it starts counting at 0... But I'm also a noob. I'm just trying to get it to compile so I can actually test everything.

Alexis I don't really know what you mean, but I guess I'll find out when I can finally get it to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `b` is a pointer to int,

```
b[PlayerCoordsX]
```

is an integer, you cannot subscript `b[PlayerCoordsX]`. You need a pointer to pointer to int:

```
int **b;
```

then you can do double indirection. Or, if you have a flat array, calculate an index instead of using double indices:

```
b[PlayerCoordsY * numCols + PlayerCoordsX] = "x";
```

If you define the board like you do:

```
int board[3][3];
```

then you can change the function signature to:

```
void PlayerTurn(int b[][3])
```

Comment: How can the compiler calculate the index in the 2D array when passing `int **b` as you suggest?

Comment: You need to allocate each row separately to do that, for your case you can use the method from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17583872/390913

Comment: @perreal This means that your answer is incorrect, because @JoeP is having an `int Board[2][2]`!

Comment: @perreal You did explain the error very clearly :-)  But you also said "with `**b` you can do double indirection"; and that's not true because replacing `*b` with `**b` is not enough for double indirection.  But hey, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Your argument `b` is a pointer to an integer.  This means that `b[PlayerCoordsX]` is an integer, and thus `b[PlayerCoordsX][PlayerCoordsY]` is basically trying to use an `int` (the "subscripted value") as a an array.

When you pass a 2D array to a function, the compiler needs to know the number of columns in the array.  This is because an array is [laid out as a linear block of memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) and the compiler needs to calculate the index in that linear array.

So you need to pass

```
void PlayerTurn(int b[][2])
{
}
```

But it would be a good idea to `#define` the size, instead of using a 'magic' value `2`.